# Как границу отрисовать внутри блока?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

div {
  height: 50px;
  width: 150px;
  background: #444;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: `outline: solid 1px #fff`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

я вас правильно понял?

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

div {
  height: 50px;
  width: 150px;
  background: #444;
  outline: 1px solid #fff;
  outline-offset: -15px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, да точно!!